# Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function on a JS function for a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm sort of new to JS and bookmarklets.

I'm modifying some existing code; which is written like this (I'm oversimplifying the actual code for the education purposes):

```
  javascript: 1 && function(e) {
    var t = "";
    t += "<style>",
    t += ".somestyle-header{ background-color: #0171C5 !important }",
    t += "</style>",
    t += '<div class="somestyle-header">Test</div>',
    t += "";
    e("body").append("<div id='something'> </div>"), e("#something").append(t)
  }($myvariable);
```

Now, this currently works and it creates a *DIV* called ***"something"*** and then appends everything on variable *"t"* to it. In other words it adds whatever is on variable **"t"** to the HTML of the current site (given that the site has the ***$myvariable*** set somewhere).

I'm trying to do something similar, but I have the following questions:

1. How can I remove that *1* at the very begining of the function and make it work?
2. How can I make it work on every page?, regardless of the
   *$myvariable* at the end being present or not.

Also, if someone can explain what that 1 at the very beginning and that $myvariable at the very end are doing and why this code doesnt work if I remove any of those parts?

I was hoping I can do something like this:

```
javascript: (function() {

  if (!($ = window.jQuery)) {
      script = document.createElement( 'script' );
      script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'; 
      script.onload=launchTheSplash;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  } 
  else {
      launchTheSplash(e);
  }

  function launchTheSplash(e) {
    var t = "";
    t += "<style>",
    t += ".somestyle-header{ background-color: #0171C5 !important }",
    t += "</style>",
    t += '<div class="somestyle-header">Test</div>',
    t += "";
    e("body").append("<div id='something'> </div>"), e("#something").append(t)
  }
}());
```

So that:

1. I check for the existence of JQuery
2. I launch my bookmarklet regardless of the existence of the $myvariable

But my code doesn't seem to work at all if I remove the 1 at the beginning or the $myvariable at the end. If I do that I get an *Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function*

Hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I've tried the suggestion below:

```
javascript: (function() {

  if (!($ = window.jQuery)) {
      script = document.createElement( 'script' );
      script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'; 
      script.onload=launchTheSplash();
      document.body.appendChild(script);
  } 
  else {
      launchTheSplash();
  }

  function launchTheSplash(e = $) {
      var t = "";
      t += "<style>",
      t += ".somestyle-header{ background-color: #011515 !important }",
      t += "</style>",
      t += '<div class="somestyle-header">Test</div>',
      t += "";
      e("body").append("<div id='something'> </div>"), e("#something").append(t);
    }
}());
```

But it doesnt seem to work on certain pages; for example -if I try to run the bookmarklet in www.apple.com website it comes back with *Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function*

Any ideas appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute functions immediately, you can use IIFE(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). The correct syntax to execute functions immediately is -

```
(function(text){
  console.log(text);
})('Hello World')
```

In your case `e` is supposed to be jquery element, so whenever you are calling launch function you should pass `$` in it.

Take a look at this snippet - https://jsitor.com/E8JW18YD-

Comment: Thanks @Ashvin777, this one does work! However, it only works if it gets into the "else"... if it gets into the "if" it gets the same "e is not a function error". I'm guessing the script.onload=launchTheSplash(); is the culprit. However I've tried adding the $ in there and it doesnt work. Any ideas? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Then inside launch function set the default value of e to $. Just like functiom launchTheSplash(e = $)

Comment: Thanks @Ashvin777, that works on some pages but not all of them. Kindly review my newest edit to the main post.